# Add alpha channel selection is not available on gimp , why?

Tags: gimp

I can not select the option add alpha channel on gimp, why? What can I do to correct that error?

Comment: Maybe you already got an alpha channel?

Comment: Is the option *Remove Alpha Channel* available?  If so, then the layer already has an alpha channel.

Comment: If you're wondering why it seems like you magically get alpha channels sometimes, it looks like GIMP will add an alpha channel automatically when you add a layer (even if that layer doesn't have a background of type Transparency); I suspect that GIMP uses alpha channels for its internal use. E.g., this caught me off guard when editing a single layer grayscale image, then it silently converted my image on save to an RGB with alpha image. Check the channels tab if you are ever in doubt.

Comment: See Also: [Why does GIMP add an alpha channel at every opportunity?](http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/16325-why-does-gimp-add-an-alpha-channel-at-every-opportunity)

Answer (score 4):

As other say, the layer already has an alpha channel.

Tip: in the Layers list (Ctrl-L), layers without alpha channels have their name in boldface, while those who have use the regular font weight.